# Spark Kinesis Streaming with Enhanced fan-out

Tags: python, apache-spark, streaming, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I am streaming data from Kinesis to Spark using - spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.4.0.jar
Below is the configuration i have

```
sdf1 = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kinesis") \
  .option("streamName", "Sample-stream") \
  .option("initialPosition", "latest") \
  .option("region", "us-east-1") \
  .option("awsAccessKeyId", awsAccesskey) \
  .option("awsSecretKey", awsSecretkey) \
  .load()
```

I changed my Kinesis user as Enhanced fan-out consumer. Once the enhanced fan-out option is enabled, above configuration doesn't work anymore. Do we have any option to consume Kinesis stream from spark as a enhanced fan-out consumer?

Looks like python boto3 also doesn't support http2. I am good with any option in python to consume from kinesis as enhanced fanout consumer.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I don’t think spark streaming supports enhanced fan out.